# Enforcing a unique relationship over multiple columns where one column is nullable

Tags: db2, db2-400, unique-index

Given the table

```
ID  PERSON_ID  PLAN  EMPLOYER_ID  TERMINATION_DATE  
1         123   ABC          321        2020-01-01
2         123   DEF          321            (null)
3         123   ABC          321            (null)
4         123   ABC          321            (null)
```

I want to exclude the 4th entry.  (The 3rd entry shows the person was re-hired and therefore is a new relationship.  I'm only showing relevant fields)

My first attempt was to simply create a unique index over `PERSON_ID / PLAN / EMPLOYER_ID / TERMINATION_DATE`, thinking that DB2 for IBMi considered nulls equal in a unique index.   I was evidently wrong...

1. Is there a way to enforce uniqueness over these columns, or,
2. is there a better way to approach the value of termination date? (null is not technically correct; I'm thinking of it as more true/false, but the business logic needs a date)

---

#### Edit

According to the docs for 7.3:

> UNIQUE
>
> Prevents the table from containing two or more rows with the same value of the index key. **When UNIQUE is used, all null values for a column are considered equal.** For example, if the key is a single column that can contain null values, that column can contain only one null value. The constraint is enforced when rows of the table are updated or new rows are inserted.
>   The constraint is also checked during the execution of the CREATE INDEX statement. If the table already contains rows with duplicate key values, the index is not created.
>
> UNIQUE WHERE NOT NULL
>
> Prevents the table from containing two or more rows with the same value of the index key, where all null values for a column are not considered equal. Multiple null values in a column are allowed. Otherwise, this is identical to UNIQUE.

So, the behavior I'm seeing looks more like UNIQUE WHERE NOT NULL.  When I generate SQL for this table, I see

```
  ADD CONSTRAINT TERMEMPPLANSSN 
  UNIQUE( TERMINATION_DATE , EMPLOYERID , PLAN_CODE , SSN ) ;
```

(note this is showing the real field names, not the ones I used in my example)

---

#### Edit 2

Bottom line, Constraint !== Index.  When I went back and created an actual *index*, I got the desired behavior.

Comment: What's your DB2 for IBM i version? My 7.4 doesn't allow me to insert 4-th record with existing 3-rd one and unique index on `(PERSON_ID, PLAN, EMPLOYER_ID, TERMINATION_DATE)`: `SQLCODE=-803`. [When UNIQUE is used, all null values for a column are considered equal](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzxcindx.htm)

Comment: I think this is the version - v7r3m0

Comment: The rule must be the same for 7.3. Please, provide a reproducible example with unique index containing nullable columns, which allows multiple nulls in one column, while values for other columns are the same.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Thanks for your attention.  Do you need more than what I just added

Comment: I got your requirement "to exclude the 4th entry" as requirement NOT allow to insert the 4-th row (with TERMINATION_DATE IS NULL), if the table already contains 1-st 3 rows. 3-rd row with the same column values already exists in the table, so, unique index (not UNIQUE constraint - DB2 doesn't allow UNIQUE constraint on nullable columns) should satisfy such a requirement. `UNIQUE WHERE NOT NULL` allows you control uniqueness of NOT NULL values only. I.e. it prevents you from inserting another row with `TERMINATION_DATE = '2020-01-01'` and with other 3 the same column values as in 1-st row.

Comment: Your understanding of the requirement is correct; I want to disallow entry of the 4th row.  I see you noticed the `ALTER TABLE` mentioned constraint and not index; I noticed that too.  I set it up as a... (facepalm)... key constraint, thinking that I was setting up an index.  They're not the same, are they?

Comment: UNIQUE constraint are technically supported by unique index. But they are not the same. When you create constraint, an index is created, but not vise versa. UNIQUE constraint can be referenced in the referential integrity constrains, but indexes can not. Difference in column nullability requirement for both types of objects was already mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215387/discussion-between-tim-morton-and-mark-barinstein).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON 
(
  ID INT NOT NULL
, PERSON_ID INT NOT NULL
, PLAN CHAR(3) NOT NULL
, EMPLOYER_ID INT
, TERMINATION_DATE DATE
);

INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, PERSON_ID, PLAN, EMPLOYER_ID, TERMINATION_DATE)
VALUES 
  (1, 123, 'ABC', 321, DATE('2020-01-01'))
, (2, 123, 'DEF', 321, CAST(NULL AS DATE))
, (3, 123, 'ABC', 321, CAST(NULL AS DATE))
WITH NC;
```

--- To not allow: ---

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, PERSON_ID, PLAN, EMPLOYER_ID, TERMINATION_DATE) VALUES 
(4, 123, 'ABC', 321, CAST(NULL AS DATE))
or
(4, 123, 'ABC', 321, DATE('2020-01-01'))
```

You may:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PERSON_U1 ON PERSON 
(PERSON_ID, PLAN, EMPLOYER_ID, TERMINATION_DATE);
```

--- To not allow: ---

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, PERSON_ID, PLAN, EMPLOYER_ID, TERMINATION_DATE) VALUES 
(4, 123, 'ABC', 321, DATE('2020-01-01'))
```

but allow multiple:

```
(X, 123, 'ABC', 321, CAST(NULL AS DATE))
(Y, 123, 'ABC', 321, CAST(NULL AS DATE))
...
```

You may:

```
CREATE UNIQUE WHERE NOT NULL INDEX PERSON_U2 ON PERSON 
(PERSON_ID, PLAN, EMPLOYER_ID, TERMINATION_DATE);
```